# Choosing countries for a council

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to select $12$ countries in the United Nations to serve on a
council if $3$ are selected from a block of $45, 4$ are selected from a block of $57$, and the
others are selected from the remaining $69$ countries?

Answer (score 1):

$\binom{45}{3}\binom{57}{4}\binom{69}{12-3-4}$

Comment: i guess some words wouldn't hurt

Comment: I guess if Siamoka read @Lord_Farin's answer and my answer, there wouldn't be anything else to say

Answer (score 0):

The relevant information for you is contained in Wikipedia, namely [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).